# Tagging Cruise questions with Ferry Tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

Cruise ships are not generally considered ferries. I think this is confusing to tag these questions with a ferry tag.

Comment: I agree. Unless there is some sense I'm not aware of whereby people can use cruise ships to ferry them around between some destinations? \-:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree, *unless* the person wants to use a cruise ship specifically as transportation from A-B. I can't imagine why anyone would want to do that, though.

Comment: It could possibly be an option for somebody who can not or will not fly if there is no other transport option between two points.